# How do I tween a variable with TweenLite?

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, tween, gsap

```
package
{
import com.greensock.TweenLite;

import flash.display.Sprite;

public class TweenTest extends Sprite
{
    private var _test:Number = 10;

    public function TweenTest()
    {
        TweenLite.to(this,1,{_test:200});
    }
  }
}
```

I get the error #1069: Property _test not found for TweenTest…
I also tried this example which does not work for me:
http://www.snorkl.tv/2010/09/how-to-tween-a-variable-with-flash-and-tweenlite/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TweenLite can only affect public properties of a class.  Making `_text` public or creating an public getter should sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible by simply making your variable public.

You can also do something like:

```
var arr:Array = [0];

TweenLite.to(arr, 1, {endArray: [10], onUpdate: output});

function output():void
{
   trace (arr[0]);
}
```